# jQuery Navigation Menu issue with trying to animate/change text color

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation

I have a navigation menu that uses jquery to provide some animation effects.

Unfortunately, something isn't working quite right.

The color is supposed to change when you hover using the animate_color function (which is being called successfully)

I have set it up in jsfiddle for you to look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/d52Z6/1/

Thanks!

Comment: i did a fiddle once to answer a similar question, [might looking at it help](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/WXYHb/)? after all, it does work and changes fonts and such

Comment: Click on JSLint in the top bar. You have a couple of errors in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to also load jQuery UI. See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/d52Z6/6/)**.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 .menu-item:hover {color:#fff}
```